# run a shell script which reference another script on ssh

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I have two bash scripts `main.sh` and a `util.sh`, and I reference `utils.sh` in the `main.sh` by using `. util.sh`. Now I want to run `main.sh` via ssh. Obviously, this won't work:

> ssh user@host "bash /dev/stdin < main.sh"

Because remote shell cannot find `util.sh`. So how should I do this, without copying `util.sh` to remote machine ?

Comment: To run a remote script `ssh user@host main.sh` would be enough actually. Why can't you just copy `util.sh` over as well?

Comment: Maybe `utils.sh` is a common module and reused by many scripts

Comment: You still can deploy it to `host` together with `main.sh`. Or put it onto a shared/network drive somewhere. Or have `main.sh` check whether it is available locally and download it from somewhere if not.

Comment: No rep to do much, but most likely this is a duplicate of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/980640/how-can-i-execute-a-script-on-a-remote-machine-over-ssh-but-source-local-files)

Answer (score 0):

Even though I think deploying `util.sh` to `host` would be the better/more stable solution, you could do something like putting this on top of `main.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

U=$(mktemp)
cat > "$U"
. "$U"
rm -f "$U"
# rest of script
```

and then run

```
ssh user@host main.sh < util.sh
```

To be more fail-safe you may require some extra coding in `main.sh` to handle issues with the temp file being unwritable/undeletable, no input passed on `stdin`etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is ugly, but should work:

```
ssh user@host bash < <(sed 's/\. util\.sh/ {r util.sh; d}' main.sh)
```

That will embed the contents of the util script into the main script, and then pipe the script to the bash process running on the remote host.
Note that I've removed the double quotes: the process substitution needs to run on your local machine where both files reside.